# User input not updating on sql databse and no error in log chat

Tags: php, android-asynctask

When I try to update my input data to my SQL database then nothing happens. I have been trying for quite a while and unfortunately nothing happens when I click the save button. I have no idea where I have gone wrong because unfortunately nothing at all shows up in log chat.

Don't know how to check something if there are no errors. Find my code and PHP below. My Fineappl and category EditText fields are not filled by user. They automatically get filled based on if else if code which takes in speed and decides how much to charge for overspeeding.

Create php

```
<?php


// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['driver']) && 
    isset($_POST['licencenum']) &&
    isset($_POST['officer']) && 
    isset($_POST['speed'] &&  
    isset($_POST['fine']) && 
    isset($_POST['category']))
{

    $driver = $_POST['driver'];
    $licencenum = $_POST['licencenum'];
    $officer = $_POST['officer'];
    $speed = $_POST['speed'];
    $fine = $_POST['fine'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];


    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO fineregister
                          (driver,licencenum,officer,speed,fine,category)
                      VALUES('$driver', 
                             '$licencenum',
                             '$officer',
                             '$speed',
                             '$fine',
                             '$category')");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Speed Ticket Successfully Registered.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
 } else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Activity.java

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import com.finecalc.library.JSONParser;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

     public class RegisterFine extends Activity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
EditText inputDriver;
EditText inputLicence;
EditText inputOfficer;
EditText inputSpeed;
EditText FineAppl;
EditText inputCategory;
TextView registerFine;
// url to create new fine
private static String url_create_fine = "http://127.0.0.1/android_api/create_fine.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Edit Text
    inputDriver = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    inputLicence = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    inputOfficer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    inputSpeed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    FineAppl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    inputCategory = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    registerFine = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fineregistered);


    // Create button
    Button btnRegisterfine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savefine);

    // button click event
    btnRegisterfine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating new product in background thread
            new CreateNewFine().execute();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Background Async Task
 * */
class CreateNewFine extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(RegisterFine.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Registering Fine..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }


    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String driver = inputDriver.getText().toString();
        String licencenum = inputLicence.getText().toString();
        String officer = inputOfficer.getText().toString();
        String speed = inputSpeed.getText().toString();
        String fine= FineAppl.getText().toString();
        String category = inputCategory.getText().toString();


        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("driver", driver));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("licencenum", licencenum));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("officer", officer));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("speed", speed));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fine", fine));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category", category));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_fine, "POST", params);

        // check log cat from response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserLogin.class);
                startActivity(i);
                //registerFine.setText("Error occured in registration");

                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

   }
  }
```

Comment: FYI, you can write `isset(x, y, z, ...)` instead of `isset(x) && isset(y) && isset(z) && ...`.

Comment: Shouldn't you use something like `$db->query()` instead of `mysql_query()`?

Comment: I guess I shouldnt be using mysql_query but it didnt cause any issues in my login register app so I stuck to it. Just dont understand my input data doesnt get updated.

Comment: change the IP in the URL http://127.0.0.1... to the PC's IP that have the webserver installed on, ex http://192.168....

Comment: I tried that as well. Infact that was my initial IP.

Comment: ok, do you have any error handling inside the DB_CONNECT()? if not, add some try/catch or die("msg ..."), then switch POST to GET in PHP page, and use a web browser on the PC to call that page http://127.0.0.1/android_api/create_fine.php?driver=xx&...
just to make sure the server side is OK, then you can move on with other possibilities

Comment: and for sure, 100% at mobile Don't use the 127.0.0.1 IP